# Multi Level subdomain redirecting to root domain

Tags: nginx, cloudflare

Trying to separate my internal and external API's, but for some reason when I do a multi tier subdomain it is just redirecting back to the root domain. I have the following nginx block set up:

```
server {

        server_name api.internal.---;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/api.internal.---.access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/api.internal.---.error.log;

        root /var/www/html/---/api;
        index index.php;

        include /etc/nginx/cloudflare/cloudflare.conf;
        gzip off;

        location / {
                #add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS' always;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Then I have a CNAME pointing api.internal to the base domain.  It works fine for single tier sub-domains, but for some reason is having issues with multi tier ones.  Also I'm using an argo tunnel, so I can't point the record directly at the IP address with an A record.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, I had forgotten the listen 127.0.0.1:8000; directive in the configuration